# How to arrange multiple views within an RCP floating window?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Views can be pulled out of an Eclipse RCP application into their own floating window. That floating window can have multiple views stacked on top of each other. However, as far as I can tell it cannot show multiple views at the same time in a layout like the main RCP application window.

I've worked around this by creating a new "Window" (see [Eclipse RCP application - Create a window programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864224/eclipse-rcp-application-create-a-window-programatically)). However, this has a number of downsides:

1. The new window has a menu bar, which I don't really want.
2. It allows two copies of a view which is marked as not allowing duplicates (one for each window).
3. Views cannot be dragged between the two windows.

My question: is there any way to configure the behavior of the floating views which Eclipse RCP creates when you pull a view out into its own window so that other views can be docked along side it?

Comment: Isn't the point of the view placement that the user places them where they want? Or is this only for the first time of opening the application?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is internal implementation you can't change.